# Asterisk cannot hang up after longer 2 minutes

Tags: twilio, asterisk, asteriskami, asterisk-ari

I am using Asterisk AGI to control incoming call from Twilio

After STREAM FILE command is executed (to play some audio file), I want to Hangup channel.

I tried execute HANGUP command and It worked if call duration < 2 minutes.

HANGUP command not woking after call longer 2 minutes.

Any solution to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen issues with chan-sip and TCP and attempt to re-use a TCP socket it should not (it was closed).

Are you using SIP/TCP perhaps with chan-sip? If you move to pjsip, it works great.

[ASTERISK-20644 - Don't always use the existing TCP connection for in-dialog requests](https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-20644)

Comment: Thank you for  your information. I'am using SIP/TLS with chan-sip. Any solution to resolve my issue without move to pjsip?

Comment: Not that I found and ASTERISK-20644 seems to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed this issue by add below code to sip.conf at `[general]`

```
session-timers=originate
session-expires=120
session-minse=90
session-refresher=uas
```

Comment: Interesting, Twilio doesn't support session-timers, https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking/troubleshooting#problem27. I guess the Asterisk platform behavior is modified somehow?